# Railroady fails because of the missing command 'dot'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dot

I'm trying to output my Graphs with the Gem railroady and i installed the gem railroady as well as the gem graphviz and if i do `bundle exec rake diagram:all` I recieve this following error:

```
railroady -lamM | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g" | dot-Tsvg > C:/Sites/blending_oil/blending_oil/doc/models_complete.svg
Der Befehl "dot" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (255): [railroady -lamM | sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1...]
```

This are my Ruby and Rails Versions:

```
ruby:
bin:        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/ruby.exe
version:    ruby 2.1.8p440 (2015-12-16 revision 53160) [i386-mingw32]

rails:
bin:        C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/rails.bat
version:    Rails 4.2.5.1
```

My Graphviz and Railroady versions:

```
ruby-graphviz 1.2.2
railroady 1.5.2
```

Why I receive this error?

Answer (score 0):

From the `Ruby/GraphViz` README.md

> INSTALLATION
>
> sudo gem install ruby-graphviz
>
> You also need to install
> GraphViz

To install GraphViz visit http://www.graphviz.org/